# share on twitter button like that of linkedin

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I want to embed LinkedIn share and twitter share on my Jekyll pages.

I have made LinkedIn share, which was pretty simple. Now, I want my Twitter share button to be like that of LinkedIn.

[image]

This is my current sharing buttons.

I want that Twitter should also show the number of shares like LinkedIn is showing.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Twitter doesn't support a counter anymore.

> The count was built in a time where the only button on the web was
>   from Twitter. Today, it’s most commonly placed among a number of other
>   share buttons, few of which have counts.
>
> Additionally, the “count API” has never existed as part of our public,
>   supported and documented API endpoints; it was only intended for use
>   by our own web widgets. We’ve often cautioned in our developer forums
>   that use of such undocumented endpoints shouldn’t be relied upon, as
>   we cannot commit to supporting them

Source: [Twitter Developer Blog: Hard decisions for a sustainable platform, Tuesday, 6 October 2015](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform.html).